# How to create advanced horizontal list animation in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, animation, gsap

I’m looking for some help with an advanced animation that I want to create. There is a gif to (hopefully) make it clearer what it is that I want if it’s not clear by the next paragraph.

Think of the interface of rows with each 5 items. In the application the user has the ability to remove an item by clicking on it. When the user does so, every item after the clicked item should move a spot to the left. If an item is already in the left most spot, the item should fit in the row above. Whenever an item moves rows, the user will see the item move left out of screen, but move into the screen at the same time in the row above the row it left.

The gif to explain it in a visual: (user taps on '8' to hide it and the user taps on '1' to hide it which means the items after the clicked items should animate to a different spot)

[image]

The array that will be used is quite extensive already so I don’t want to change much about that array. At first I was thinking of modifying that array into an array of arrays where you can see the first arrays as the row. The markup would be like this:

```
<section *ngFor="let blockRow of orderedBlocks" class="block-row">
  <article [attr.data-id]="block.id"  *ngFor="let block of blockRow" class="block" [style.backgroundColor]="block.bgColor">
    <p [innerHTML]="'ID = ' + block.id"></p>
    <ion-button (click)="completeBlock(block.id)">complete block</ion-button>
  </article>
</section>
```

Which would create the following layout: [image: layout of markup]

Adding the animations with:

```
animations: [
trigger('items', [
  transition(':enter', [
    style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' }),
    animate('.5s ease-in-out',
      style({ transform: 'translateX(0) }))
  ]),
  transition(':leave', [
    style({ transform: 'translateX(0)'}),
    animate('.5s ease-in-out',
      style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' }))
  ])
])
```

Would make it so **everything** changes like that on every change instead of the individual items.

However like I said, I don’t like this one. Whenever something changes within the item (which is possible in the real application) every single item will re-render since we need to convert it to this special array again.  Nope, doesn’t sound like a good thing performance wise to do this every single change.

Alright, maybe the modulo operator would do the trick so we don’t have to modify the original array? I was unable to figure this out as well.

I’m able to use Angular Animations or even gsap, but I’d love it if this was possible without any mutations on the array really. Is it possible and if it is, how?

Comment: One thought is to add a trackBy function on the *ngFor. This way, only if the tracked property changes then the binding will change, and the animation will trigger. Have you tried that?

Comment: @BenBradshaw Would that be needed on both *ngFor loops? I know that the trackBy is nice in that it only does things with the changed item instead of a whole re-render but I'm not sure if that's a solution for this. Would using the animation from above and the trackBy actually result in the animation from in the gif? How would one go about the structure of the data? Does it need to be an array of arrays or can it be one big array where the template will divide it in rows? Sorry for all the questions, although I do like the animation, it's quite hard for me to understand how to pull it off.

Comment: Yes, on both. I understand what you mean more now. I suspect that modifying the array and letting the animations react to the array changes would be a good way to do it. In terms of the exact animation using the animation api, it will take some time and work. You might have a simpler implementation using CSS3 animations, although, the angular animations do give you the added benefit of the :leave query.

Answer (score 0):

When an item is clicked, you will need to either

1. Absolutely position all of your elements or
2. Wrap all of the items in a row in a container that will be animated.

Then you will need to duplicate all of the items that are going to wrap to a different line (either to the container of the previous row or absolutely position it where it needs to be).

Then you need to animate each of the containers (or absolutely positioned elements) that you want to animate to the left by one box (and spacing around it) amount.

It'd also be much easier if you disable the ability to click on a second box while the previous animation is still going.